# Queue timer in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, timer

What would be the simplest way to implement knockout bindings for a customer queue timer? I am not that good with knockout and my search found only questions about countdown timers. I don't where exactly should I start with this. Custom binding? Manual refresh? Every advice is appreciated.

I have an observable array which contains my customer models, one of the properties of the customer model is EnqueueTime which contains the time, when the customer entered the queue. I want to display the time customer has spent in the queue (time span between the EnqueueTime and current time).

So far, I am just showing the value of EnqueueTime. This is just a snippet from my testing code I currently use, later it will be getting some reasonable form and data:

```
this.Customers = ko.observableArray();    
var vm = {};
vm.CustomerNote = "Test";
vm.EnqueueTime = Date.now();
vm.Priority = true;
this.Customers.push(vm);
```

And the view:

```
<div id="customerQueue" class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Note</th>
                    <th>Time in queue</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Customers">
                <tr data-bind="css: {danger: Priority}">
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="visible: Priority" class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: CustomerNote"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: EnqueueTime"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a few objects active at a time, a good quick solution is to use a computed observable. However since nothing else changes, you'll need an external observable that can be updated independently to refresh the displayed values.

Here's a quick example:

```
var vm = { models: ko.observableArray() };

var trigger = ko.observable(null).extend({ notify: 'always'});

class Model {
  constructor(time) {
    this.EnqueueTime = time;
    this.Elapsed = ko.computed(() => {
        trigger(); // read observable to be able to update when it updates
      var date = new Date(null);
        date.setTime(new Date() - this.EnqueueTime);
      return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    });
  }
}

vm.models.push(new Model(new Date()));
vm.models.push(new Model(new Date(2018, 1, 1)));

setInterval(() => trigger(null), 1000);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/AlexPaven/vnk92gt7/

Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: This works just fine, the list won't ever get over something like 50 items. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, you should probably use something like momentJS for date/time calculations and not my one liner which is for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: Oh yeah, I am using moment. Thanks again.